# Schematic of switching power supply 230V to 5 / 3.3 VDC

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, schematics

I would like to ask you if you have the schematic of the power supply mentioned below. There are various variations but the input is always AC 85-265V 50/60 HZ while the output is, depending on the model either 5VDC or 3.3 VDC. The maximum output current it can deliver is around 500 mA.

The power supply is the following and could be purchased from various sources on the Internet (eBay, Amazon, Alibaba, etc.)

[image: Switching Power Supply]

So far I have identified the following electronic components on the PCB:

- THX208 - PWM Switching Power Supply Controller
- MB6S - 0.5A Bridge Rectifier
- LTV-356T OPTOISOLATOR 3.75KV
- Electrolytic Capacitor 10V/1000 uF
- Electrolytic Capacitor 400V/4.7 uF
- Electrolytic Capacitor 25V/22 uF
- High Frequency Transformer (no visible marking on the transformer)

Additionally there seems to be in SMD:

- Zener diode
- Led
- Capacitors
- Diodes
- Resistors

But their printing is to small for me to read with our a magnification glass (which I do not have yet)

Comment: SE is not your personal research team to assign tasks to. Do some work yourself - try a little reverse engineering or listing the part numbers of the chips/transistors/capacitors.

Comment: I agree with you, however before spending hours of research and staring at uber small SMD components would not it be better to ask if someone has a schematic design? I'll see if I can identify some components on the PCB board and list them.

Comment: NO, you ask here and you get ten naive people trying to do YOUR work. That's laziness in my book. Put some glasses on and do the right thing and stop wasting people's time.

Comment: Apparently Let Me Google That For You is banned from comments. So Google "offline power supply schematic" and start reading

Comment: Here's @Daniel's link that takes you straight to all the schematics contained on google. You will see that there are thousands so, if you add the chip number into the search it might restrict the search to maybe a hundred: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=offline+power+supply+schematic&espv=2&biw=1299&bih=873&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiC9pmQyN3JAhVG-Q4KHQILDEMQsAQIIg

Comment: Also, why would you want to a circuit diagram of a cheapo chinese made power supply that is sold thru alibaba.com?

Comment: I've identified some components on the PCB and added them to the initial post as well. The power supply is the only small power supply I could find that can deliver the voltage with the 350 mA that I need to power some components and a small 5V or 3.3V relay (switching 230V/5A). Space is pretty limited so I can't use any "normal" transformers in the power supply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you need to do:

Step 1: Google it

Open the link Andy gave. Or search for offline power supply. You will see lots of schematics. Pick a few which seem simple and manageable with the knowledge you have. Out of those, narrow down your search by eliminating those ICs which are too expensive/not easily available where you live. ST Viper22a is one of the cheap and most commonly solutions available.

Step 2: Datasheets and app notes are your best friends

Once you have decided the IC, look for the datasheet and app notes for that particular IC. You will find all details inside. Try to understand what each part does by dividing it into small logical parts. For ex - Rectifier, filter, switch etc. Unless you understand the circuit, it'll be too difficult to make it and you will never know what went wrong.

Step 3: Get your hands dirty

Buy the parts you need. In these power supplies, flyback transformer is the most tricky part, everything else is simple. For transformer, try to break apart a transformer, count the number of turns, figure out the transformer package etc - Or give the sample to a local vendor who will replicate that for you. Once you have the basic working circuit, then you can think about adding filters to improve the output.

If in between you encounter any issues, you can post what you did and people will most likely help you.

Comment: Thanks for the structured feedback, a very clear and useful approach to (reverse) engineer an electronic schematic. I've been looking at the viper22a dataset and schematics and in first glance it looks like I could use this as well. I understand how most of the components work inside the schematic but I need to educate my self a bit on the working and characteristics flyback transformers.

Comment: Marc, are you intending on making your own clone of this supply? For the time and energy involved, surely it must be 10x easier and less costly just to buy one. Or build one from scratch - then this will be all yours. Google "switchmode power supply designer" or similar, you'll find there are many tools available to design your own custom switcher.

Comment: I'm looking for a power supply with a very small footprint that can give me max. 500 mA output at 5 Volt.It needs to be put on a PCB board that is 40mm x 40mm and the max. height it has is 16mm.There are some other components on the board as well such as a relay.I've looked around the Internet for power supplies that are small and fit my tech. specs. The one mentioned does but with PCB it does not for the height, putting the components on the main PCB board will make it work.

Comment: EE16 core transformer will do your job easily. That's the tallest part in power supply. Try to stick with SMD components. For capacitors, you can use through hole and make them lie down as shown in your picture. Usually diameter is less than height so it will help reduce the height. Viper22a will be easy to work with because it accepts a wide voltage range as VCC.